# How to access static members of a class?

Tags: c++, static

I am starting to learn C++ and Qt, but sometimes the simplest code that I paste from a book results in errors.

I'm using `g++4.4.2` on Ubuntu 10.04 with QtCreator IDE. Is there a difference between the g++ compiler syntax and other compilers?  For example when I try to access static members something always goes wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
   public:
      static int x;
      static int getX() {return x;}
};
int main()
{
   int A::x = 100; // error: invalid use of qualified-name 'A::x'
   cout<<A::getX(); // error: : undefined reference to 'A::x'
   return 0;
}
```

I think it's exactly the same as declared [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm) (isn't it?). So what's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've declared the static members fine, but not [defined](http://dietmar-kuehl.de/mirror/c++-faq/ctors.html#faq-10.12) them anywhere.

Basically what you've said "there exists some static member", but never set aside some memory for it, you need:

```
int A::x = 100;
```

Somewhere outside the class and *not* inside main.

Comment: Isn't this a declaration: static int getX(){return x;}?

Comment: In that context it's declaring and defining getX() at the same time. Without the {return x;} it would be just a declaration. The definition is "the bit that makes it work" which is an implementation or some actual storage.

Answer (score 14):

Section [9.4.2]

**Static Data Members**

> The  declaration  of  a static data  member  in  its  class  definition  is  not  a  definition  and  may  be  of  an incomplete type other than cv-qualified void.  **The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition**.  In the definition at namespace scope, the name of  the static data  member  shall  be  qualified  by  its  class  name  using  the `::` operator

Answer (score 11):

You need to define the static member variable of the class outside the class as static member variables require declaration as well as definition.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
   public:
      static int x;
      static int getX() {return x;}
};

int A::x;         // STATIC MEMBER VARIABLE x DEFINITION

int main()
{
   A::x = 100;    // REMOVE int FROM HERE
   cout<<A::getX();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why we need `int A::x;` c++ is SOOOOO ugly

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
   public:
      // This declares it.
      static int x;
      static int getX(){return x;}
};

// Now you need an create the object so
// This must be done in once source file (at file scope level)
int A::x = 100;


int main()
{
   A::x = 200;
   // Notice no 'int' keyword before A::x on this line. You can modify A::x

   cout<<A::getX(); // Should work
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok. it works. but for template classes, gives this error: too few template-parameter-lists. (I write int SP<int>::free = 100;)

Comment: @Sorush Rabiee: Sorry I am not psychic. You are going to have to show some code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `inline` keyword since c++ 17 in front of `static` members to avoid a definition outside of class scope. Your code should now look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
   public:
      inline static int x;
      static int getX() {return x;}
};
int main()
{
   A::x = 100;    //Works now
   cout<<A::getX()<<'\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The definition of static member variables must live at file scope, i.e. outside all functions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class check
{
        static int a;
    public:
        void change();
} ;
int check::a=10;
void check::change()
{
    a++;
    cout<<a<<"\n";
}

int main()
{

    int i,j;
    check c;
    check b;
    c.change();
    b.change();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can't we just write check::a = 10; (without "int" specifier)? I mean, check::a was already declared as int

Comment: The syntax for defining a non const static variable outside the class is "Return_type class_name :: static_variable = Initialization ". if we miss the return type, compiler throws syntax error. The same is applicable for defining a member function outside the class

Answer (score 1):

Now you have worked out how to use static class members I will advise you that you should generally use them only in the following circumstances:

- For use in templates. So in your example you could have GetX() in different classes and in a template somewhere you would use

  ```
  template< typename T >
  int func()
  {
      return T::GetX();
  }
  ```

  although obviously more elaborate. But here your static function being in a class serves a purpose.
- Where the function needs access to the class, i.e. to private members. You could make it a friend but you may as well make it static. Often the case in callbacks.

The rest of the time you can probably use compilation-unit level functions and variables which has the advantage of taking your members out of the header (particularly if they are private). The less implementation detail you give the better.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: **static variable**

As we all know, defining a static variable inside a class which will throw compilation error. E.g. below

```
class Stats
{
  public: 
     static int AtkStats[3];
     *static int a =20;*        // Error: defining a value for static variable
};

int Stats::AtkStats[3] =  {10, 0, 0};
```

Output:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'Stats::a'
```

Case 2: **const static variable**

For **const** static variable, we can define a value either inside a class or Outside class.

```
class Stats
{
  public: 
     static const int AtkStats[3];
     static const int a =20;        // Success: defining a value for a const static
};

const int Stats::AtkStats[3] =  {10, 0, 0};

const int Stats::a = 20;        // we can define outside also
```

Output:

```
Compilation success.
```