# Access static variable in a different class in C++/Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, static, unreal-engine4

I have a static variable declared in a header file and initialized in the corresponding cpp file. What I'm trying to do is accessing that variable from another cpp file. This is the code:

**AkOcclusionObstructionService.h**

```
class AkOcclusionObstructionService
{
public:

    static float OcclusionFadeRate;
    ...
}
```

**AkOcclusionObstructionService.cpp**

```
...
float AkOcclusionObstructionService::OcclusionFadeRate = 3.0f;
...
```

**MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.cpp**

```
#include "MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "AkOcclusionObstructionService.h"

void UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary::ChangeWwiseFadeRate(float rate)
{
    AkOcclusionObstructionService::OcclusionFadeRate = rate;
}
```

---

When I try to build Visual Studio gives me this error:

"*LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: static float AkOcclusionObstructionService::OcclusionFadeRate" (?OcclusionFadeRate@AkOcclusionObstructionService@@2MA)*".

It looks like *MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary* can't see the *OcclusionFadeRate* variable in the *AkOcclusionObstructionService* cpp file.

Anyone has an idea of what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Additional Linking/building info:

To make the "*AkOcclusionObstructionService.h*" file visible to the "*MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.cpp*" file we had to add something to the "*TestFadeRateWwise2.build.cs*" (TestFadeRateWwise2 is the project name).
Specifically we had to add "AKAUDIO" to this line:

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "AKAUDIO" });
```

That's the only "non standard" thing we did.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you show that is inherently wrong, so the fault must be in the code you don't show or the way you compile it.

Comment: This is not a code but a build issue. How do you build (or in your case link) your code?

Answer (score 1):

in the cpp file
you should do like this.

```
//.cpp
#include "MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "AkOcclusionObstructionService.h"

//this line make this file to access the static parameter.
float AkOcclusionObstructionService::OcclusionFadeRate;

void UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary::ChangeWwiseFadeRate(float rate)
{
    OcclusionFadeRate = rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell based on the code you posted but I assume the issue is because the line below is within a function:

```
float AkOcclusionObstructionService::OcclusionFadeRate = 3.0f;
```

Move that line outside the function and try it again. You can take a look at this question: [How to access static members of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104544/how-to-access-static-members-of-a-class)

Comment: There's no reason to believe this is in a function. We're told that line is in the AkOcclusionObstructionService.cpp file.  OcclusionFadeRate = rate; IS in a function, maybe that's what you meant.